# calculate the sum based on multiple groupby's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and a dict as follows:-

```
    dict_min_count = {'A':1,'B':4,'C':2,'D':3}

    df:-
    
    mac_type Test  time_diff
    1        A     567
    1        B     2
    1        B     6
    1        B     8
    1        B     9
    1        B     8
    1        C     99
    1        D     1
    1        D     2
    1        D     10
    1        D     1
    2        A     2
    2        A     12
    2        A     21
    2        B     22
    2        B     12
    2        C     2
    2        C     3
    2        D     1
    2        D     3
    2        D     12
    2        D     12
```

By using these 2 data I need to calculate the sum by using some conditions:
1)for any test for a mac_type i need to calculate the sum for only first n rows that is present in the dict_min_count dictionary.

example:for Test A no need to calculate the sum as the value is 1.for Test B for each mac_type calculate sum for 4 rows. If 4 rows are not there calculate it for the number of entries which are there(in case of mac_type 2 we have only 2 entries for machine B so sum will be for only those 2 rows)

The final results I am looking at is as follows:

```
              Tests
    mac_type  A      B          C         D
    1         567 (2+6+8+9)     99     (1+2+10)
    2         2   (12+22)      (2+3)  (1+3+12)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom function with [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html) with match values by dictionary then `sum` and last [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
dict_min_count = {'A':1,'B':4,'C':2,'D':3}

df = (df.groupby(['mac_type','Test'])['time_diff']
        .apply(lambda x: x.head(dict_min_count[x.name[1]]).sum())
        .unstack())
print (df)
Test        A   B   C   D
mac_type                 
1         567  25  99  13
2           2  34   5  16
```